# How can I get the count of elements in a list using xaml when bound to a label in xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-databinding

code for 'Data'

```
     public ObservableCollection<Graph> Data { get; set; }
```

Graph object:

```
      {public class Graph : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private TimeSpan time;
private double units;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public TimeSpan Time
{
    get { return time; }

    set
    {
        time = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
    }
}

public double Units
{
    get { return units; }

    set
    {
        units = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
    }
}
}
```

'Data' is a list of 'Graph' objects and I need to display the value of the 'Unit' in the last Graph object of the list, 'Data'. How can I do it in xaml with data binding?
This is what I tried and it doesn't work:

```
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Data[Data.Count-1].Units}"/>
```

Really appreciate the help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below.

ViewModel:

```cs
public class GraphViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Graph> Data { get; set; }
    public GraphViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Graph>()
        {
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=1 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=2 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=3 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=4 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=5 },
        };
    }

}
```

Xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>

    <Label  Text="{Binding .}"/>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    GraphViewModel viewModel;
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new GraphViewModel();
       
        this.BindingContext = viewModel.Data[viewModel.Data.Count - 1].Units;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) for this.

Example:

// ViewModel

```
public class GraphViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Graph> Data { get; set; }
    public GraphViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Graph>()
        {
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=1 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=2 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=3 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=4 },
            new Graph(){  Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0), Units=5 },
        };
    }
}
```

// Converter

```
public class LastGraphUnitsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IList<Graph> data)
            return data.Last().Units;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // not needed for this example
    }
}
```

// ContentPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:graph="clr-namespace:Graph;assembly=Graph"
         x:Class="Graph.MainPage"
         x:DataType="graph:GraphViewModel">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <graph:LastGraphUnitsConverter x:Key="LastGraphConverter"></graph:LastGraphUnitsConverter>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Data, Converter=LastGraphConverter}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

[The sample from Wendy Zang - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966143/2448833) might technically work, but I would advise always keeping the ViewModel as the BindingContext.